# Setting DataGridView.RowCount to NumericUpDown.Value adds extra column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

So I have a form on which I have a NumericUpDown control (I'll call it my num picker), and a DataGridView (I'll call it my grid).  My grid is currently unbound and I manually added columns to it in design, and when I run my form it's all fine.  So in the code I added this method:

```
Private Sub numPicker_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles numPicker.ValueChanged
    DataGridView.RowCount = CInt(numPicker.Value)
End Sub
```

With that, at runtime my grid has an extra un-titled column in the front.  If I comment out the assignment there is no extra column...if I uncomment it there is an extra column.

I have another form with a similar setup and for whatever reason that form acts fine...there is no extra column being added.  So I just have no idea why one form would add a column to my grid and another wouldn't...nor do I have any idea how to deal with it.

Any ideas?

NOTE for clarification:  MSDN's article on the RowCount property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states "If you set the RowCount property to a value greater than 0 for a DataGridView control without columns, a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn is added automatically."  But I do already have columns. And in the form Load I set the row count to 1 (the num picker's value is also 1). When that assignment line is commented out, my form loads with 1 row in the grid and no extra column.

Comment: With that event what are you trying to do? Is it adding the extra column when you change the numPicker.Value or not OR just at runtime there's an extra column?

Comment: The ValueChanged event is setting the number of rows in the grid to the value that is in the num picker. They both start out at 1, so say the user changes the num picker to 2, then that adds a row in the grid so the number of rows is 2. But at runtime the grid simply has an extra Column that I did not create (changing the number of rows by changing the num picker's value works fine, and doing this does not change the number of columns).

Comment: I just created a DataGridView with two columns tied to a NumericUpDown control, it work's just fine; when 1 there's only 1 row and so on... Do you have anymore code or can you post screenshot of your columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ValueChanged() event is firing and then changing the number of rows **before** the DataGridView has been completely initialized.

Add a check in there and the extra column should go away:

```
Private Sub numPicker_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles numPicker.ValueChanged
    If DataGridView.IsHandleCreated Then
        DataGridView.RowCount = CInt(numPicker.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, man...you're right!  Adding that check worked - there is no more extra column.  Thank you so much!